# How to get list of available Activex controls

Tags: windows, windows-registry, activex

In RegEdit are registered all of the ActiveX. Is there a way to make a list of the available controls, not browsing in the RegEdit?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first listing on googling "List all ActiveX Controls"

[ActiveXHelper](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/axhelper.html) provides you a GUI to look at all your ActiveX Controls

Answer (score 0):

I use [OLEViewer](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=5233b70d-d9b2-4cb5-aeb6-45664be858b6&displaylang=en) from Microsoft.

Comment: dead link here...

Comment: @RubberDuck That's not surprising, this answer is 4 years old and the product is no longer supported.

Comment: Yeah. Kind of the problem with questions like this.